# Will a warm object in a vacuum cool more quickly than a warm object surrounded by an atmosphere containing CO2?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have gotten stuck on an endless thread about Global Warming, in which skeptics sometimes make the claim that an object surrounded by a "heat absorber" like CO2 will cool more quickly than one not surrounded by something that absorbs heat, because the "heat absorber" will absorb heat from the warm object, speeding its cooling.  I think this is likely complete nonsense, but would like to see what people with greater expertise have to say. If it is false, a nice, simple explanation to fire back with and try to set these people straight would be much appreciated!
  Could this be tested by lab experiment?  Has it been? any links?

Comment: The fact of CO2 being a "heat absorber" _is the problem_. Warm objects emit infrared energy. Some of the infrared energy that is radiated from the Earth's surface gets absorbed by CO2 instead going out into space, and that aborption raises the temperature of the atmosphere.

Comment: Tell them not to turn on their home furnace in the winter because they don't want a "heat absorber" like air being circulated through their house.

Comment: The answer depends on a LOT of things.  What is the temperature of the hot object?  How much does it's temperature change?  The hot object emits IR radiation, but CO2 absorbs IR radiation in very particular wavelengths.  What temperature and pressure is the CO2 at?  Is there any CO2 wind on the hot object (is this natural convection or forced convection)?  What is the temperature of the surroundings that the hot object's IR energy is going into?  This question DOES NOT have a nice, simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

The object can be the planet Venus. If Venus would be a shiny white rock without an atmosphere, its surface temperature would about -40 C. But the surface temperature is about 460 C.

The CO$_2$ in the atmosphere radiates as much as it absorbs, half of it downward half of it upward.

https://www.acs.org/content/acs/en/climatescience/energybalance/planetarytemperatures.html

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the situation!

If you have a thermos flask setup, where your warm object is surrounded by some medium and then by air, then the carbon dioxide cools it faster. This is because there's better thermal contact - the carbon dioxide molecules collide with the warm object and carry away some energy, whilst if there's a vacuum then all cooling has to be done by radiation, which is slow.

If, on the other hand, you have a setup more like Earth's climate, where you have a warm object, a boundary layer, and a vacuum, and a constant inflow of energy (from the Sun), then you find that the warm object stays warm for much longer if there's carbon dioxide. This can be shown with a fairly simple treatment, like the [idealised greenhouse model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idealized_greenhouse_model).